# VBA code to remove entire row when a specified value is found, is not working

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my code which is giving me error "Type mismatch", please review and assist.
Thank you!

```
Sub removedata()

Dim rng As Range
Dim c As Range

Set rng = Columns(1)

    'Removing unwanted data sets
    For Each c In rng
    If c.Value = 50100 Then
        Rows.EntireRow.Select
        Selection.Delete
    End If
    Next c
       
End Sub
```

Comment: Already tried putting "" around value 50100"Removing unwanted data sets
For Each c In rng
If c.Value = "50100" Then
    Rows.EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Delete
End If
Next c

Comment: This would be much easier with `Range.AutoFilter`, instead of looping.

Answer (score 2):

`Rows` is a property of a range object it can't exist on its own like you have it, unless it's returning a value: `rows(1)`.

Don't delete while looping, deleting shifts everything you can potentially miss some of the criteria.

```
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim wksheet As Worksheet
    
    Set wksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    With wksheet
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
    End With
    
    Dim deleterange As Range
    'Removing unwanted data sets
    For Each c In rng
        If c.Value = 50100 Then
            If Not deleterange Is Nothing Then
                Set deleterange = Union(deleterange, c.EntireRow)
            Else
                Set deleterange = c.EntireRow
            End If
        End If
    Next c
    if not deleterange is nothing then
        deleterange.Delete
    end if
```

I added in a worksheet reference and changed your range to be `Column A Row 1` to `Column A Last Row` Instead of the entire column A, no need for 1 million + iterations.

If you want to instead use an autofilter:

```
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim wksheet As Worksheet
    
    Set wksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    With wksheet
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
    End With

    rng.AutoFilter 1, 50100

    rng.Offset.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1, rng.Columns.Count)(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    rng.AutoFilter
```

Answer (score 1):

Autofiltering is an easy way to do it. Alternatively you could loop backwards deleting empty rows. Something like this:

```
Sub remove_empty_data()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Dim r As Long, i As Long

r = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With ws
    For i = r To 1 Step -1
        If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1)) Then .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```